# Accent not rendering in R markdown

Tags: r, utf-8, r-markdown

I have this part of my code and I can't figure out how to work around this.
my accents as ?

here is the full code :

```
###############
#Requete 1
###############

#Nombre de décès en milieu hospitalier

Table_1=dbGetQuery(conn=database_Covid19, statement = "SELECT SUM(Décès) AS Effectif 
           FROM COVID19 WHERE DATE=18913")

Table_1 = gt(Table_1)

Table_1 <- 
  Table_1 %>%
  tab_header(
    title="Nombre total de décès en milieu hospitalier",
  )

Table_1
```

It renders as :

```
Nombre total de d�c�s en milieu hospitalier
Effectif
87964
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unicode characters:

```
title="Nombre total de d\u00e9c\u00e8s en milieu hospitalier"
```

Comment: I don't have @Zwi's problem on my system, but if your solution works for them, an easier version of it is to use the `enc2utf8` function, i.e. `title=enc2utf8("Nombre total de décès en milieu hospitalier")`.  That way you don't need to remember the Unicode code points.

Comment: @user2554330 on my machine this solution doesn't work, it is interesting, i have tried it too... Edit, ha-ha) I made ```title="enc2utf8(Nombre total de d\u00e9c\u00e8s en milieu hospitalier)"``` My dumb head ;)

Comment: neither of the 2 solutions seemed to work, it still render as questionmarks, hopefully it renders as é and è in the pdf file. but thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Zwi strange, where do you work, in Linux?

Comment: @manro no, on windows 10

Comment: @Zwi I don't know. Try to reopen file with UTF-8 ```File -> Reopen with encoding```.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`enc2utf8(Nombre total de d&eacute;c&eacute;s en milieu hospitalier)`